# Copying old database with flat data to a new database with normalized data

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have an old database that is a single flat table.  I want to copy the old data to the new db structure.  Both are MSSQL databases.  Here's a simplified example of what I want to do:

```
OLD_DB                                     New_DB

Customers_Table             Customers_Table         Phone_Numbers
---------------             --------------          -------------  
FirstName                   CustomerID              PhoneNumberID
LastName          -->       FirstName               CustomerID
PhoneNumber1                LastName                PhoneNumber
PhoneNumber2
PhoneNumber3
```

I understand how to copy the flat data.  This seems to work just fine:

```
INSERT INTO   New_DB.dbo.Customers_Table (FirstName, LastName)
SELECT        FirstName, LastName
FROM          OLD_DB.dbo.Customers_Table
```

I just don't know how to get the phone numbers into the new structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your FirstName and LastName are your unique identifiers, you can run this using `UNION` after you run your above statement:

```
INSERT INTO New_DB.dbo.Phone_Numbers (CustomerId, PhoneNumber)
SELECT C.CustomerID, OldC.PhoneNumber1
FROM New_DB.dbo.Customers_Table C
  JOIN OLD_DB.dbo.Customers_Table OldC ON C.FirstName = OldC.FirstName 
     AND C.LastName = OldC.LastName 
     AND OldC.PhoneNumber1 IS NOT NULL
UNION
SELECT C.CustomerID, OldC.PhoneNumber2
FROM New_DB.dbo.Customers_Table C
  JOIN OLD_DB.dbo.Customers_Table OldC ON C.FirstName = OldC.FirstName 
     AND C.LastName = OldC.LastName 
     AND OldC.PhoneNumber2 IS NOT NULL
UNION
SELECT C.CustomerID, OldC.PhoneNumber3
FROM New_DB.dbo.Customers_Table C
  JOIN OLD_DB.dbo.Customers_Table OldC ON C.FirstName = OldC.FirstName 
     AND C.LastName = OldC.LastName 
     AND OldC.PhoneNumber3 IS NOT NULL
```

Alternatively, you could use `UNPIVOT` and run something like this (I've condensed it for testing, but same concept):

```
SELECT Id, Phone 
FROM ( SELECT id, phone1, phone2, phone3 FROM Phone ) p
UNPIVOT
(Phone FOR Phones IN (phone1, phone2, phone3))AS Phone
```

Here is the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/339e3/1) for the `UNPIVOT`:

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Select the phone numbers, join in the new company table to get the id (assuming of course that the FirstName and LastName combinations are unique), do a union between three queries for three phone numbers, and insert into the new table:

```
insert into New_DB.dbo.Phone_Numbers

select c.CustomerID, o.PhoneNumber1
from New_DB.dbo.Customers_Table c
inner join OLD_DB.dbo.Customers_Table o
  on o.FirstName = c.FirstName and o.LastName = c.LastName
where o.PhoneNumber1 is not null

union all

select c.CustomerID, o.PhoneNumber2
from New_DB.dbo.Customers_Table c
inner join OLD_DB.dbo.Customers_Table o
  on o.FirstName = c.FirstName and o.LastName = c.LastName
where o.PhoneNumber2 is not null

union all

select c.CustomerID, o.PhoneNumber3
from New_DB.dbo.Customers_Table c
inner join OLD_DB.dbo.Customers_Table o
  on o.FirstName = c.FirstName and o.LastName = c.LastName
where o.PhoneNumber3 is not null
```

Note: This will create duplicate phone numbers if a customer has the same phone number in more than one of the fields. You can use `union` instead of `union all` to remove those duplicates.